# How to upload a file to a document library given a HttpPostedFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a HttpPostedFile object and after the file gets uploaded locally onto the server, i want to move that temp file into a document library in sharepoint.  Here is my code:

```
private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses) {
            for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++) {
                HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[i];
                file.SaveAs(ingestPath + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
}
```

Can anyone give me some example code for this?  I have found a tutorial for Streams, but not quite sure if it would work the same in my situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the two lines starting with `file.SaveAs` with the following:

```
var myDocumentLibrary = SPContext.Current.Web.Folders["MyDocumentLibrary"];
var myFile = myDocumentLibrary.Files.Add(file.Name, file.FileContent, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a code sample for you that comes in parts:

Here is code that gets the Files content into a byte array buffer:

```
var file = (HttpPostedFileBase)Request.Files[0];
var buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength];
file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, file.ContentLength);
var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/_temp");
var temp_file_name = "somefilename";
var path = Path.Combine(root, temp_file_name);

using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var br = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
        br.Write(buffer);
    }
}
```